# How to determine the specific app that calls or triggers a Firebase Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Basically I have multiple apps(Android & iOS) connected to a single Firebase Project. I would like to determine which specific app (iOS Bundle Id or Android Package Name) that calls or triggers a firebase function. For example depending on the specific package name or bundle id, when a user is created, I would like to do different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No information about the app is passed along to the `user.onCreate()` Cloud Functions trigger, as the trigger is actually caused by the Authentication backend.

If you want different behavior based on the triggering app, consider implementing a [callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) and passing the information along from your application code yourself.